# Condition for lines joining origin to the point of intersection(s) of two curves to be perpendicular

Tags: analytic-geometry, homogeneous-equation

Given curves:
$$ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx=0$$
$$a_1x^2+2h_1xy+b_1y^2+2g_1x=0$$

It is given that the lines joining the origin to the points of intersection of these curves are perpendicular to each other.

We've to prove that:
$$\boxed{g(a_1+b_1)=g_1(a+b)}$$
using **homogenisation**

###### My approach

Let $lx+my=n$ be the line passing through the points of intersection.
$$\frac{lx+my}{n}=1$$

Now, transforming the curves into second degree homogenous equations, we get:
$$ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx\frac{lx+my}{n}=0$$
$$a_1x^2+2h_1xy+b_1y^2+2g_1x\frac{lx+my}{n}=0$$

These are the required lines.

How to proceed from here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does it mean to take the ratio of two equations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3338899/what-does-it-mean-to-take-the-ratio-of-two-equations)

Comment: Although it is closely related, I'm specifically asking for the answer based on homogenisation.